# Does Windows Update also update Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

This question may be relevant to any version of Windows where Windows Update is present, as I imagine the answers might be different between versions.

(Also, my apologies if this question should have been placed somewhere else, I looked for a Windows forum on SE and couldn't find one.)

I'm writing system requirements for a web application that requires at least IE8, and would like to communicate in the documentation how the user can make sure they have the latest browser version (on Windows) without having to download it manually, if possible. However being on OS X I'm having a hard time managing to find out if Windows Update will actually update IE (from say, 7 to 8) on Windows XP? What about later versions like Windows 7 or 8?

As a side note, Microsoft won't (by default anyway) even let my OS access any areas of their website where I might find a download link to Internet Explorer 8 or any other version since I'm not on Windows. Just sayin', if I wanted to supply a link to our users, that is. Yes, I  will fire up my VM or PC to get the link but it seems... unnecessary?

Anyway, can I tell our users they just need to fire up Windows Update to make sure they're running IE8, or do I need to ask them to check version manually and download a new version manually (if necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Windows Update generally does update critical IE components, major updates are generally considered optional updates that are not installed unless the user chooses to install them manually.

Consequently, you'll likely need to include a download link.  Try http://microsoft.com/ie/download, which should redirect to the language appropriate page for the given user.

(Also, some users choose to not run Windows Update, so the download link may be needed anyway.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Answer (score 1):

To answer your query "Anyway, can I tell our users they just need to fire up Windows Update to make sure they're running IE8, or do I need to ask them to check version manually and download a new version manually (if necessary)?"

Yes, windows update also update Internet explorer.
To change setting for windows update where you can choose which updates is related to your OS and components and you can download and install to avoid unnecessary downloads.
Please find below steps to change the settings
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\Change settings

Under Important updates option you will find

Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will be an 'optional' windows update. In this case the user will still have to select and accept it, but windows update will do the rest. I would advise your users to check Windows Update for the latest browser version.

Answer (score -1):

IE is part of Windows OS so I guess Windows update take care of IE like any other Windows components

Comment: A guess is not really an answer, sorry.